# What is the truth value of this nested quantified statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$$ \forall x \exists y ((x \lt y) \implies (x^2 \lt y^2)) \space where \space x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

I used proof by contradiction and found that it is true. However my professor thinks it is false because if for example x=-5 and y=-2 then $x^2 \lt y^2$ would be false.

To my understanding, the statement means that for every x there exist at least 1 y that satisfies the statement. Am I misunderstanding this or is my professor incorrect?

Comment: While it is true that if $x = -5$ and $y = -2$,  $x^2 < y^2$ is false; but that's not what the statement is saying (afaik).   It's saying that there exists a $y$ such that $x < y$ and $x^2 < y^2$.    So if you have $x = -5$ then take $y = 6$.

Comment: Both $y=x-1$ and $y=|x|+1$ satisfy the above.

Comment: Note that the inner statement is vacuously true when $x \ge y$.

Comment: @ewokx That would be $\forall x\exists y((x<y)\land(x^2<y^2))$, which is different. The way OP wrote it, it means "for every x there exists a y such that either $x<y$ is false or $x^2<y^2$ is true" (recalling the truth table for $\Rightarrow$).

Comment: Recall that $\exists x\in A$ is shorthand for $\exists x(x\in A\land\dots)$ while $\forall x\in A$ is shorthand for $\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow\dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it does appear that your professor is incorrect. If the statement was for all x AND for all y, where x is less than y, then what your professor said would make sense. But in this case you're correct, it's simply talking about the existence of at least one y for each x that satisfies the statement.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\forall x \exists y ((x \lt y) \implies (x^2 \lt y^2)) \space where \space x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

This statement is indeed true: given any $x,$ putting $y=x$ renders the parenthetical implication vacuously true.